# Need to remove rows that exist before flag value

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to remove the rows (highlighted in yellow) that exist prior to the `FirstOrder` flag (partitioned by `CustomerID`).

[image]

The business case is that I need to remove the rows for each customer that has a row before their First Order date (ASOFDATE where FirstOrder=1).

I have attempted the creation of another column that coalesces the minimum date per customer and the minimum date per FirstOrder, to create a kind of range, but where I was stymied was how to account for the NULL's in between those dates. The one idea I had was to make those in between dates the same as the first date, then I could simply remove rows where this proposed "reference date" < (asofdate where firstorder = 1), but I'm not having luck getting that to work:

[image]

I'm sure the solution is pretty simple and I'm just not seeing it. Here's the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #DATA (ASOFDATE DATE, CUSTOMERID INT, ACTIVE BIT, FIRSTORDER BIT)
INSERT INTO #DATA VALUES
('2018-01-31',  206424, NULL,   NULL),
('2018-02-28',  206424, NULL,   NULL),
('2018-03-31',  206424, 1,      1),
('2022-06-30',  206424, NULL,   NULL),
('2022-07-31',  206424, NULL,   NULL),
('2018-06-30',  247034, NULL,   NULL),
('2018-07-31',  247034, NULL,   NULL),
('2018-08-31',  247034, 1,  1),
('2022-05-31',  247034, NULL,   NULL)
```

Comment: Would there ever possibly be a case where a customer has more than one FIRSTORDER record? The different solutions below will yield different results in such cases.

Comment: Valid question, but no there's only one first order. That is calculated before this dataset based on the MIN(AsOfDate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a conditional sum() over() may help

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select * 
      ,Flag = sum( case when FirstOrder=1 then 1 else 0 end ) over (partition by CustomerID order by asofdate)
 from #Data
)
Delete from cte where Flag=0
```

**Updated Table**

```
ASOFDATE    CUSTOMERID  ACTIVE  FIRSTORDER
2018-03-31  206424      1       1
2022-06-30  206424      NULL    NULL
2022-07-31  206424      NULL    NULL
2018-08-31  247034      1       1
2022-05-31  247034      NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! Because my whole data set will comprise of hundreds of thousands of rows, I will probably shy away from the CTE approach, but I don't believe I understand why this works.

Looking at it again, it must be the OVER() that confines the results with the firstorder being the "starting point" based on customer id? Is that what it's doing?

Comment: @jw11432 Your understanding of the sum() over() is correct.   However, I think you may be underestimating what the CTE does and how it performs.

Comment: Perhaps. My understanding of the CTE is that it's good for a small number of rows, but when you start getting into 100's of thousands of rows, if not millions, then a temp table is a better option. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @jw11432 There's an old saying ... "One test is worth a thousand expert opinions."  :)

Comment: This is the best answer as it avoids a `SELF JOIN` operation. I don't know why it didn't come up on my mind, but you should definitely use it for your task and flag it as the answer of your post. @jw11432

Comment: @JohnCappelletti lol fair enough my friend. Perhaps I'll try both and see how it fares.

Comment: @lemon That's interesting. I wouldn't have thought a self join would be an issue, but I suppose thinking about it, I can kinda see why that might be a performance gain. I'll definitely need to read up a bit on that. Unfortunately, tuning for performance is a weakness of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another working option is matching your table with a selection of your table where "*FIRSTORDER*" is true. Then remove all "*CUSTOMERID*" matching rows which have a lower "*ASOFDATE*" than the corresponding "*FIRSTORDER*".

```
DELETE #DATA
FROM       #DATA 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ASOFDATE, CUSTOMERID FROM #DATA WHERE FIRSTORDER = 'True') firstOrders
        ON #DATA.CUSTOMERID = firstOrders.CUSTOMERID
       AND #DATA.ASOFDATE   < firstOrders.ASOFDATE;
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2386dd346a8a2af0013dbb3f4308c699).

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was trying to do, it just wasn't coalescing in my head properly lol thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WITH StartDates AS (
    SELECT CUSTOMERID, MIN(ASOFDATE) AS StartDate
    FROM #DATA
    WHERE FIRSTORDER = 1
    GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
)
DELETE D
FROM StartDates S
JOIN #DATA D
    ON D.CUSTOMERID = S.CUSTOMERID
    AND D.ASOFDATE < S.StartDate
```

See [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8fed0da1ccb3faf9641e1382184bd90a)

The CTE (common table expression) first picks the FIRSTORDER reference date for each customer, and the main query then uses that information to select the records to be deleted.